Enigma (Oxyd based) game, 0.92 -3, level #4 "Seed Puzzle"
From page 203 of the Enigma Reference Manual (PDF readable here),

Stone seeds are items that start growing and finally transforming [sic] to stones on activation. [...] Seeds can be dropped on any item-free grid position, even beneath another stone that will get killed by the seed successor stone.

Also, from page 282,

[A oneway block, which is the type in the level with an arrow on it, is] A stone with one special face, that allows actors [such as the black marble controlled by the player] just to pass from inside to outside but not vice versa. The other faces can generally be passed in both directions. As most times it is more important to be aware of the passages which are blocked, you may remember that the oneway's arrow points to the side that can not be entered

In Enigma we have the following level:

We have 6 seeds and need to open all black stones. I have an idea of how to do it with more seeds: put 4 of them under one-sided arrows to the left and right parts, then add 2 times 3 to obtain the paths between the upper and lower parts. Additionally, at least 1 seed is needed to go back to the central part.
But how 6 seeds can be enough?

Hello, it will be very helpful to other readers to describe how the game works in the question and not require the readers to go to the link and read the question.

From page 203 of the Enigma Reference Manual (PDF readable here),

Stone seeds are items that start growing and finally transforming [sic] to stones on activation. [...] Seeds can be dropped on any item-free grid position, even beneath another stone that will get killed by the seed successor stone.

Also, from page 282,

[A oneway block, which is the type in the level with an arrow on it, is] A stone with one special face, that allows actors [such as the black marble controlled by the player] just to pass from inside to outside but not vice versa. The other faces can generally be passed in both directions. As most times it is more important to be aware of the passages which are blocked, you may remember that the oneway's arrow points to the side that can not be entered.

With that in mind, let's solve the puzzle:

 We will be planting our seeds underneath these six oneway blocks:



 Start by moving to the top of the level, then travelling through A. (The X block just past it is a door - presumably, it allows the player through, but disallows turning A into a stone and pushing it leftwards.) Touch the Oxyd (the "black stones" we seek to touch), plant a seed under A, and push it rightwards until it's just past B.
 Plant under B, push the resultant stone down, then slip sideways through the other oneway so that you can move down and around to where C is. Push A all the way left, then go through C, touch its Oxyd, plant beneath it, and push the new stone past B again.
 Travelling through the broken oneway again lets you reach the lower part of the level, where you can repeat this sequence of steps once more with your three remaining seeds. From there, travel up and enter the central room through the right side and touch the Oxyds contained within.

Side note:

 Oxyds must be touched in matching pairs - the above solution presumes the pairs of corner Oxyds are "top two" and "bottom two". If this is not the case, the B and E plantings can be done first, and the corners should be clearable in any order.


Thank you! The base of the trick is that the one-way blocks are accessible also from their sides. I have not enough reputation to also upvote your answer, but I will remember about it.

I would appreciate if you took the information from the beginning of my answer (along with an explanation of the doors and the Oxyds, including their pairing) and worked it into your original post. Once you do that, your question will be better suited to other solvers on the site, and you may earn more reputation.

I hope that it is an enough edit. (I forgot that 100 points of reputation are added from other sides of my StackExchange activity).
